# VBA Userform Date/Time Stamp - UK Date changes to US format when copied to cell

Tags: vba, excel, date, datetime

I have a userform that has a date and time stamp dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.

It shows in UK format in the text box, and I generate it using this code:

```
Dim iNow
Dim d(1 To 6)
Dim i As Integer


iNow = Now
d(3) = Year(iNow)
d(2) = Month(iNow) & "/"
d(1) = Day(iNow) & "/"
d(4) = Hour(iNow) & ":"
d(5) = Minute(iNow) & ":"
d(6) = Second(iNow)

For i = 1 To 6
  If d(i) < 10 Then Timestamp = Timestamp & "0"
  Timestamp = Timestamp & d(i)
  If i = 3 Then Timestamp = Timestamp & " "

Next i
datetextbox.Value = Timestamp
```

The issue occurs when the following block of code transfers this information to the Excel database sheet using the following code:

```
'Determine emptyRow in Database Sheet
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
Cells(emptyRow, 14).Value = datetextbox.Value
```

What happens is the date changes to MM/DD/YYYY when it enters into the spreadsheet cell. I have tried number formatting in VBA and also on the drop down menu and used custom settings, and checked that the regional settings are UK on two separate machines. This is an integral part to a document I have created, that will recognise the most recent record of the same reference number using this formula which then transfers data to a cleansing sheet:

```
=MAX(IF(Database!$P$2:$P$1437=P488,IF(Database!$P$2:$P$1437=P488,Database!$N$2:$N$1437,"")))
```

I did try a simple Now() stating the format dd/mm/yyyy/ hh:mm:ss but this also converts to US format.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that you could also use `Timestamp = Format(Now,"DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss")`. If your regional format uses something other than `/` as a divider you need to use an additional "\": `"DD\/MM\/YYYY"`. Timestamp should probably be `Dim`ed as `String` so you don't end up with a `Date` type,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this has been answered many times before on here, but you need to use `CDate`:

```
Cells(emptyRow, 14).Value = CDate(datetextbox.Value)
```

This will convert the date string to a true date value using your regional settings.

Comment: Thank you for posting, it works perfectly! Everything else I found posted without the knowledge of CDate was going about it the wrong way by focusing on populating the text box in a certain way or formatting the cells with vba.

Comment: Is there a way to tell `CDate` (or any other function) how to interpret the string? It uses the regional settings (I think) which works in this case but what if I want to read an american style date string?

Comment: If you want to use an American format, you don't need `CDate` at all. VBA will default to US formats.

Comment: Ok but what if an American wants to read a "DD/MM/YYYY" date? I would think that there should be something like `CDate(string,format)` but apparently there isn't.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct We're getting a little off topic here, but why would they see a date in UK format in a userform? You can use `Format` to return a formatted string in whatever format you specify.

Comment: You're right, this is getting off topic and my question is kind of exotic. I am mostly interested understanding/controlling when and how VBA converts using which settings. I run into problems caused by regional settings quite often due to my machine settings.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct VBA will interpret using US settings when it has to coerce anything **implicitly** - eg converting a date string to a true date value. Any explicit conversion using the C- functions will use regional settings.